# CakePHP :: Changing The Way It Is Sending Form Data [Passwords]?

Tags: cakephp, passwords

I have built a form using the CakePHP form helper and I am trying to get it to change my users password, that should not be to hard. But for some reason when I submit the form it submits in plan text.

```
    $UsersPass = $this->Form->create('PasswordUpdate', array('id' => 'ChangePassword', 'url' => '/update_password'));
    $UsersPass .= $this->Form->input('oldpassword', array('div' => false, 'type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Old Password'));
    $UsersPass .= $this->Form->input('passwordnew', array('div' => false, 'type' => 'password', 'label' => 'New Password'));
    $UsersPass .= $this->Form->input('passwordconfirm', array('div' => false, 'type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Confirm'))l 
    $UsersPass .= $this->Form->submit(' ', array('div' => false, 'type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'Button_DoneSubmit') ); 

    echo UsersPass;
```

Any way of getting CakePHP to make sure that it does not submit in plan text?

thanks.

Comment: Submitting will always be in plain text. That is just how the world works - or in this case HTTP/POST. Ideally you would do that using https/ssl by the way. Tip: You can also try [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/).

Comment: thanks - I am building it off line for now in my own LAMP VM. When I make the site live, will cakePHP deal with HTTPS for me, once its setup? I have never worked with HTTPS before, not sure how it works with my code. I would take it that it is more of a config over code?

Comment: CakePHP (and basically any scripting framework) will just-work with https. That's a server-level thing, not an application thing.